# how to enter a placeholder & a value within the same text box

Tags: php, html

I want to watermark a text box with a variable.

I've got it working by doing:
`placeholder="<?php echo $user;?>">`

This puts the correct information in the text box as a watermark. However if I don't enter any information in that text box (because I want the data to remain the same) it clears the data stored in the `$user` because I have not updated the record.

Comment: Why use a placeholder at all instead of just the value?

Comment: Purely because if there is multiple text boxes, tells the user what information needs to be in each box etc. rather than using labels really

Comment: @j08691 comments above

Comment: So why not just use a PHP condition. If the user is not set then post user will be equal to user. that's to set a default value.

Comment: any reason you don't just use CSS to make it look like placeholder text until it's focused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not particularly a PHP solution (for which I would recommend Ben's answer), if you need to have the value, then you can just use CSS to have the values display as placeholders and then use `:focus` to make it look like a regular input tag.

You could also use a `data-*` attribute and then use Javascript/jQuery on submit to set the values to the data attribute you designate.

```css
input[type="text"] {
  color: darkgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Placeholder value" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't set a value for the input but it's reliable even when the user has intentionally submitted an empty input:

```
if (strlen($_POST['user']) == 0) {
  $_POST['user'] = $user;
}
```

You can also make a function out of it:

```
function nullCheck($index, $default = 'UNKNOWN') {
  if (strlen($_POST[$index]) == 0) {
    $_POST[$index] = $default;
  }
}
```

Then call it:

```
nullCheck('user', $user);
```

But I'm not sure if you put the post variables(in the function) as: `{$_POST[$index]}`, because it might consider the index variable as a separate variable.

NB: *This code is untested*